Python 3.12 Sentry-sdk AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
I tried to use sentry-sdk latest version with Python 3.12, but when I run my django app, it shows me following error:
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Full trace as follows:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from sentry_sdk.hub import Hub, init
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/hub.py", line 5, in <module>
from sentry_sdk.scope import Scope, _ScopeManager
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/scope.py", line 11, in <module>
from sentry_sdk.attachments import Attachment
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/attachments.py", line 5, in <module>
from sentry_sdk.envelope import Item, PayloadRef
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/envelope.py", line 6, in <module>
from sentry_sdk.session import Session
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/session.py", line 5, in <module>
from sentry_sdk.utils import format_timestamp
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/utils.py", line 1302, in <module>
HAS_REAL_CONTEXTVARS, ContextVar = _get_contextvars()
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/utils.py", line 1272, in _get_contextvars
if not _is_contextvars_broken():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/utils.py", line 1213, in _is_contextvars_broken
from eventlet.patcher import is_monkey_patched  # type: ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from eventlet import convenience
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
from eventlet.green import socket
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 21, in <module>
from eventlet.support import greendns
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 78, in <module>
setattr(dns, pkg, import_patched('dns.' + pkg))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 60, in import_patched
return patcher.import_patched(module_name, **modules)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 132, in import_patched
return inject(
       ^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 109, in inject
module = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dns/namedict.py", line 35, in <module>
class NameDict(collections.MutableMapping):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

What is your sentry-sdk version?
